# Sum of values for items from list in single cell excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table (Table a) with a list of materials and material pricing the columns are material_name and material_price.

I have a separate list of assemblies. the list of assemblies contains all materials in a single cell separated on their own row.

E.g.:

```
material 1
material 2
material 3
```

I am trying to create a sum of material prices for each assembly. I need the formula to review each material in the assembly search forthe price in table a and sum it to create a sum of material prices for each assembly.

Assemblies are of varying size. some are a single material some are up to 10  materials.

I'd really like to be able to maintain the formatting for the assemblies as it's listed above for easier readability. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit - Thanks for the pointers

Expected Result:

Sum of all the items contained in the assembly. Sum will be derived from material price in table A

[image: Sample table]

Link to copy of sheet:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LAc53RLWJy-tYzcpLjsmxr1wJ0IcJit7?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: This would be easy (you could use `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($B$2:$B$200,F4)),$C$2:$C$200))` ) but in your example there are sometimes duplicate names and these won't be summed. As far as I can tell you will have to change the design of your spreadsheet or write VBA to solve this. I may be wrong, I look forward to finding out.

Comment: That's a really cool solution, but obviously you're right it doesn't recognize duplicates. I essentially need to replicate the functionality of a python for loop in excel but it's proving more difficult than I thought.

If I find a solution I'll make sure I post it here for you to see

Comment: I received this answer for the same question but in google sheets. I know this won't work in excel but for anyone searching for an answer to this question they may be able to fit it to excel or may be able to use sheets:

=sum(arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(split(F5,char(10)),B:C,2,0),0)))

Link to the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70160932/sum-of-values-from-table-using-list-in-single-cell-to-determine-items-to-sum-g

If any1 is able to answer this question in excel that would still be helpful just wanted to post the answer for sheets in case it helps with the logic.