# Sum of values from table. Using list in single cell to determine items to sum: Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table (Table a) with a list of materials and material pricing. the columns are material_name and material_price.

I have a separate table (Table B) that has the assembly name, assembly materials and assembly price. The assembly materials is a list contained in a single cell. Each material is on its own row

I am trying to create a sum of material prices for each assembly. In Table B Cell F3 contains 4 materials on their own line. In cell G3 I want to look at each material in cell F3 reference against table A to find the correct price for each material and sum all of the materials prices to create a total assembly price that includes the price of all materials listed in cell F3

Assemblies are of varying size. some are a single material some are up to 10 materials.

I'd really like to be able to maintain the formatting for the assemblies as it's listed above for easier readability. Any help would be appreciated.

Expected Result:

Sum of all the items contained in the assembly. Sum will be derived from material price in table A

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1iZ6.png)

Using the example above: In cell F3 there is a list of assembly materials. For each of the materials in cell F3 I would like to grab the price of that material from Table A and sum it against the rest of the materials in cell F3. I would like the sum of those materials to be presented in cell G3 as the Assembly Price.

Here's a link for the Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1anebCM6jDAYlksZm7ASdrj9mnwhJozKBQKDv6PpxDoA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, in G5

```
=sum(arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(split(F5,char(10)),B:C,2,0),0)))
```

Comment: Sorry this one doesn't seem to work.

Cell G6 the sum should be $1.96 I don't think any of the other assembly prices work either. I'm not sure what went wrong in cell G6 but one of the issues in the other assembly prices appears to be that it does not sum multiple instances of the same material.

Comment: ok, there are 2 problems that I can't solve for the moment: the mix between the elements starting with a number and with text, and the duplicated elements

Comment: i have updated my proposal, let me know if now it is correct!

Comment: Wow incredible, I don't know how any of it works but it works on my sample set of 26 Assemblies.

Is it pretty robust or is there a bit of fitting to the sample set? I'll definitely be spending the morning trying to break this down and understand it better because this is incredible. Thanks Mike

Comment: I hope ... no, I think it's robust and finally quite simple ... try first `split(F5,char(10))` to see the decomposition, then I just apply vlookup to fetch the cost of each item and finally I sum the different results.